# How can izitoast ng-repeat in agularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in self.quantitativeEvaluationQuestions">
            <th>{{ item.key }}</th>
            <td ng-bind="self.completeInfo[item.value] | quantitativeEvaluationOptionsFilterVc"></td>
          </tr>
```

how can i repeat in array with angularjs in izitoast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem for izitoast does not understand angularjs.
to solve this problem, angularjs gave us $compile().

```
          self.quantitativeEvaluationQuestions = [
            {
              key:'foo',  
              value:'bar'
            },
          ];
          
          const rawHtml = 
            `
            <tr ng-repeat="item in self.quantitativeEvaluationQuestions">
                <th>{{ item.key }}</th>
                <td ng-bind="self.completeInfo[item.value] | quantitativeEvaluationOptionsFilterVc"></td>
             </tr>
            `;
         
            const compiledHtml = $compile(rawHtml)($scope);
```

use with $timeout:

```
            $timeout(() => {
              iziToast.show({
                inputs: [
                  [compiledHtml[0].outerHTML, function (instance, toast) {}]
                ],
              });
            });
```

or use with $apply:

```
      $scope.$apply()
      iziToast.show({
         inputs: [
           [compiledHtml[0].outerHTML, function (instance, toast) {}]
         ],
      });
```

Comment: this soultion worked, thanks. but i wish iziToast could render angualrjs instead Behavior like string.